# How to find the bihomogenous polynomials cutting out the graph of a rational map.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the Segre surface $Q=\Sigma_{1,1}\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ given by $T_0 T_3=T_1 T_2$. Let $p=[0,0,0,1]\in Q$ and consider the projection $\pi_{p}$ of the whole $\mathbb{P}^3$ from $p$:
$$ \pi_{p} :\mathbb{P}^3\dashrightarrow Z(T_3)\cong\mathbb{P}^2, [T_0,T_1,T_2,T_3]\mapsto[T_0,T_1,T_2].$$

Let $\pi$ be the restriction of $\pi_{p}$ to $Q$, and consider the graph $\Gamma_{\pi}$ of $\pi$. I want to figure out the bihomogenous polynomials cutting out $\Gamma_{\pi}$.

Let $Q_0=Q\backslash Z(T_0)$, then the restriction of $\pi$ to $Q_0$ is a regular map and an isomorphism. Set $T_0=1$. I guess $\pi$ "takes" p to $Z(u_0)$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ since $\pi([1,T_1,\lambda T_1,\lambda T_{1}^2])=[1,T_1,\lambda T_1]$. But I can't find suitable bihomogenous polynomials to show that my guess is correct...

Answer (score 0):

Choose coordinates $[\lambda_0:\lambda_1]$ on the first copy of $\mathbb P^1$ and $[\mu_0:\mu_1]$ on the second, then $\pi:([\lambda_0:\lambda_1],[\mu_0:\mu_1])\mapsto [\nu_0,\nu_1,\nu_2]=[\lambda_0\mu_0,\lambda_0\mu_1,\lambda_1\mu_0]$. It is evident that the graph of $\pi$ is a subset of $V=Z(\nu_0\mu_1-\nu_1\mu_0,\nu_0\lambda_1-\nu_2\lambda_0)$. By considering charts $U_{ij}$ of the form $(\lambda_i\neq 0,\mu_j\neq 0)$ one checks that all points of $V$ except to the points of subvariety $\{([0:1],[0:1],[0:\nu_1:\nu_2])\}$ have the form $(q,\pi(q))$ for $q\in Q\backslash\{p\}$, hence $V$ is irreducible and it is the graph of $\pi$.

Comment: emmm...$\Gamma_{\pi}$ should be a subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^3\times\mathbb{P}^2$, not $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: $\pi$ is a map from $Q$, so its graph is a subset of $Q\times\mathbb P^2$.